# Subtract month from date and ignore summer/winter time in R

Tags: r, date

Here is my example:

```
library(lubridate)
sample_date <- as.POSIXct('2017-04-01')
sample_date %m-% months(1)
```

it gives me:

```
"2017-02-28 23:00:00 CST"
```

While I would like to have:

```
"2017-03-01 CDT"
```

How can I ignore summer/winter time difference?

**Update**

I guess it is not possible to have `"2017-03-01 CDT"`, but I would take as well 
`"2017-03-01 CST"`

Bigger question. I mostly work with dates and never with datetime, what format should I use to avoid this summer/winter time altogether?

Comment: Since you are using `lubridate` so I think you should try `sample_date <- ymd('2017-04-01')` to parse date string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `Date` object if you are not interested in the time part:

```
library(lubridate)
sample_date <- as.Date('2017-04-01')
sample_date %m-% months(1)
#> [1] "2017-03-01"
```